# Jquery UI dialog and blocking issues

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, jquery-dialog

I am using Jquery UI Dialog box with FullCalendar plugin.

My problem is UI Dialog box is non blocking.

FullCalendar has a callback function, `eventResizeStop`, and inside this callback function, I am planning to include a dialog box for user input.

```
eventResizeStop: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view) {

    $('#testDiv').dialog({
                     autoOpen: true,
                     modal: true,
                     width: 500,
                     buttons: {

                         "Ok": function () {
                             event.id = 123;
                             $(this).dialog("close");
                         }

                     }

                 });

   }
```

The problem is this callback function operation is not getting blocked on showing this dialog.
It just continues its operation and calls `EventResize` function within FullCalendar plugin.

I used blocking loops to prevent the behavior, but the page is becoming non-responsive and that's causing issues.

*How to make this a blocking event?
Or suggest me some other plugin which has this functionality.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new fullcalendar function which can resize my event when I initiate call from my UI.So the method I followed is to remove the eventResize from my resize stop handle inside fullcalendar plugin and call it separately once it is finished.

This requires including a new property function to handle the call from UI and then redirecting from their to a specific view's function.Say from Calendar's function->Views function and call event resize.

Of course this requires variables being passed back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

kind of hard to debug, but based on what you described, what happens when you leave the function empty like so

```
eventResize: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc) {}
```

or

```
eventResize:
```

or don't add the call in your object definition or even put a return false; in the function.  if you could provide a code block, this might help in the debugging.

i hope this helps.

Comment: eventResize function I was talking about is the one inside fullcalendar plugin.I think the core problem is non blocking Jquery Dialog, when I use an alert the control stays within the page. I need a work around so that this function waits until I get a response from user.

Comment: doesn't this example take into an account of a user event [link](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventResize/).  sorry, if i'm not understanding the full question.

Comment: each event is a div element and is attached with a mouseup and mouse down events..only functions available for the user to manipulate are callbacks from the fullcalendar plugin.

Comment: can BlockUI be used for this kind of scenario?

Comment: I ended up creating a new fullcalendar function which can resize my event when I initiate call from my UI.So its like remove the eventResize from my resize stop handle and call it separately once it is finished.